# How to import data of a text file skipping the Primary Key column in to a MySQL Database

Tags: mysql

I want to import data from a text file into MySQL Database, Here my requirement is to auto increment the ID (Also the Primary Key) column without importing it from the text file. I also have set ID column as Primary Key, Non-Negative and Auto-Incrementing.

The code I have used

```
use vehicledetails;
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/Test.txt'
INTO TABLE vehiclespeeddetail
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

When I run the above code I get an error saying

Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'ID' at row 1

My Text file is of as follows

[image]

I want an output with an Auto Incrementing ID Column by importing data from the above text file:

[image]

Comment: You list the column names as the end of the  SQL (`col_name_or_user_var` per the [load-data manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)). Omit the AI column from this llist.

Comment: consider if it suites to have `Date` and `Time` combined into a `DateTime` column. This can be done with `LOAD DATA` too. Will the queries be simpler that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an explicit list of columns that excludes the Auto increment column:

```
use vehicledetails;
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/Test.txt'
INTO TABLE vehiclespeeddetail
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(`Date`, `Time`, `NoPlate`, `CurrentSpeed`, `MaxSpeed`, `OverspeedDetection`);
```